# Как добавить QWebEngineView в дизайнер Qt Creator-а?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator, ui

Проблема заключается в том, что не могу добавить элемент класса QWebEngineView в дизайнере Qt Creator. Там(в дизайнере) такого класса просто не существует. Его можно добавить только через свой программный код, иначе у меня не получаеться

Answer (score 1):

Помещаете на форму обычный `QWidget`. Открываете `ui` в текстовом редакторе и ищите строчку `<widget class="QWidget" name="someWidgetName">`. Меняете `QWidget` на `QWebEngineView`. Сохраняете, перезагружаете `ui`.

Также советую ознакомиться с возможностью преобразования стандартных виджетов в виджеты, реализованные в коде. Нажать левой кнопкой по виджету и выбрать `Преобразовать в...`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно загружать .ui динамически через `QUiLoader`, переопределив метод `createWidget`, при обработке можно заменять стандартные виджеты или добавлять новые. Для добавления нового в .ui нужно создать виджет, нажать на нем правой кнопкой и выбрать "преобразовать", или что-то вроде того. Должна появиться таблица, в которую можно добавить имя класса, которое будет обрабатываться загрузчиком.

Можно вместо этого использовать QML, в котором есть WebEngineView, заодно получите и все достоинства QML.

И можно создать QML, состоящий из одного WebEngineView, и добавить его в .ui через `QQuickWidget`.

На практике, использование `QUiLoader` - это единственный оправданный способ использования ui, при использовании в качестве генератора c++ классов получается очень неудобный в поддержке код, проще и удобнее сразу писать на c++, особенно если реализовать простой  builder для Layout. Что-то вроде такого:

```
makeVBox()
    .add(makeVBox().aligment(Qt::AlignHCenter).add(new QLabel(tr(header))))
    .add(addHBox()
            .add(makeContent())  
            .add(makeMenu())   
    ) 
    .bindTo(this); // this->setLayout(...)
```